# How to get a fixed sidebar to display nicely when viewed from a smartphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, sidebar

I'm using bootstrap along with some custom css for my simple webpage. I have a fixed sidebar that keeps its position as the user scrolls through the `#content` div. However, when the webpage is viewed on a smartphone (or a the width of the browser gets smaller), the sidebar acts wonky instead of nicely occupying the top part of the website.

The behaviour I'm looking for is the same that [Twitter's bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) has. Decrease the width of your browser to see what I mean.

My current structure is like this:

```
<div class="span3" style="position:fixed">
    // sidebar stuff
</div>

<div class="span8 offset3">
    // content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries for that.

> A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions
>   that check for the conditions of particular media features.

This media query expresses that the style sheet is usable on devices with viewport (the part of the screen/paper where the document is rendered) widths between 400 and 700 pixels:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 700px) { … }
```

**source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/**

Comment: This seems to be what bootstrap is doing in their css as well. Thanks.